# How to Return to App on Notification Click

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am showing a notification in Android. This is working fine. Now **I want to focus MyApp if the User clicks on the Notification**. I know I can pass an Intent to the Notification, so I could start any Activity I want. But I do not wont to start a specific activity, I just want to go back into the app. And if the App is not running then I want to start the app normally and also not a specific Activity.

So those three scenarios:

A: MyApp is running in background, but does not have focus
**-> Focus MyApp**

B: MyApp is not running
**-> Start MyApp normally**

C: MyApp is running and also has focus
**-> Do nothing**

*My Code for the Notification:*

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(intent) // -> here I could parse an Intent, I know... 
                                      //    But that is not exactly what I want
```

I found nothing on Google for that. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Try this as pending intent:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This will :

1. If app not running, start the app.
2. If in foreground, will do nothing, focus again to the app.
3. If in background, (most probably, as far as I can recall) will focus the app and will not create activity if already created.